# where to get instrument sounds for for ubuntu music software?

Tags: music, midi

Soundfonts midi or  other to play with midi keuboard on ubuntu ? Any body know softfonts or  software  synth or sequencer to play ubuntu ?

Answer (score 1):

The packages you need:

```
$  sudo apt-cache search sf2
awesfx - utility programs for AWE32/64 and Emu10k1 driver
freepats - Free patch set for MIDI audio synthesis
gigtools - command line tools for Gigasampler and DLS Level 1/2 files
opl3-soundfont - OPL3 SoundFont that simulates the sound of an OPL3 chip
sf3convert - MuseScore SoundFont converter
sfarkxtc - Converts soundfonts from legacy sfArk v2 file format to sf2
texlive-latex-extra - TeX Live: LaTeX additional packages
timgm6mb-soundfont - TimGM6mb SoundFont from MuseScore 1.3
timidity - Software sound renderer (MIDI sequencer, MOD player)
```